# bind dynamic chart using webmethod

Tags: jquery, html, charts, html5-canvas

i am trying to bind dynamic  chart using `webmethod` as shown in bellow code . the `webmethod` return data correct but i couldn't bind it dynamically to `datapoints`

```
  <script>
        function RealCallWM() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Home.aspx/getCityPopulation",
                data: null,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: function (data, status) {
                    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                        title: {
                            text: "Stores Sales chart"
                        },

                        data: [//array of dataSeries              
                          { //dataSeries object

                              /*** Change type "column" to "bar", "area", "line" or "pie"***/
                              type: "column",
                              dataPoints: [

                               { label: "banana", y: 18 },
                              { label: "orange", y: 29 },

                              ]
                          }
                        ]
                    }
                )
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

i need to bind `datapoints` Dynamic using data. also web method as shown bellow code   . any help?

```
public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
public decimal  Value { get; set; }
public string id { get; set; }
[WebMethod]
  public static List<MakeChart> getCityPopulation()
{
    List<MakeChart> p = new List<MakeChart>();
    string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SMA_DEVEntities"].ConnectionString;
     SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connString) ;

        string myQuery = "select sum(AMTSALES) as value,[NAME]  from  [SMA_DEV].[dbo].[STORE_SALES] where RPTDATE is not null group By ID  ,NAME ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = myQuery;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                sb.Append("{");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
                string color = String.Format("#{0:X6}", new Random().Next(0x1000000));
                sb.Append(string.Format("text :'{0}', value:{1}, color: '{2}'", dr["NAME"].ToString(), dr["value"].ToString(), color));
                sb.Append("},");
                MakeChart cpData = new MakeChart();
                cpData.DepartmentName = dr["NAME"].ToString();
                cpData.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["value"].ToString());
                p.Add(cpData);
                cpData = new MakeChart();
            }
        }
        sb = sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
        sb.Append("]");

        return p;
    cn.Close();

}
```

Comment: where is you array of dataSeries and dataSeries object ?

Comment: 'data' contains webmethod return

Comment: i don't see this `webmethod`

Comment: how does sb.ToString(); look like?

Comment: contain data like '{{text :'ALX', value:963843.22, color: '#14C98C'},{text :'CFC', value:688465.25, color: '#FE7678'}}'

Comment: what you presented there is invalid, you need a array not another object

Comment: what should i do ?

Comment: create a valid json and serve it to the ajax

Comment: how to do , its first time to use webmethod

Comment: add the corect header for the json type

Comment: i am not familiar with this language so i can't help you

Comment: i modified my webmethod return to list of objects how i bind this objects to chart ?

Comment: how does the output look like now?